# How to overwrite apiman.gateway-endpoint default property values in Apiman (1.3.1.Final)

Tags: wildfly-10, jboss-tools, apiman

**Environment**

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS

Release:    16.04

Codename:   xenial

**Bug**

I'm using dockerized apiman version 1.3.1.Final. (Quite old I know...)

I'm trying to overwrite gateway properties for the [apiman-default-config.json](https://github.com/apiman/apiman/blob/apiman-1.3.1.Final/distro/data/src/main/resources/bootstrap/apiman-default-config.json) file :

```
"Gateways" : [ {
"id" : "TheGateway",
"name" : "The Gateway",
"description" : "This is the gateway.",
"createdBy" : "admin",
"createdOn" : "2016-05-16T12:34:15Z",
"modifiedBy" : "admin",
"modifiedOn" : "2016-05-16T12:34:15Z",
"type" : "REST",
"configuration" : "{\"endpoint\":\"${apiman.gateway-endpoint:https://localhost:8443/apiman-gateway-api}\",\"username\":\"${apiman.gateway-endpoint.username:apimanager}\",\"password\":\"${apiman.gateway-endpoint.password:apiman123!}\"}" } ]
```

So my thought is that I could overwrite those properties from  **apiman.properties** configuration file.
But it seems that, for example, property **${apiman.gateway-endpoint.username}** isn't evaluated and use the default value 'apimanager' in any case.

So now, my question is **how should be overwriten the following properties** ? :

```
apiman.gateway-endpoint
apiman.gateway-endpoint.username
apiman.gateway-endpoint.password
```

If it's a bug, is it fix in later Apiman version ?

I could overwrite the entire file, but if I could avoid that, it would be great...

Regards

Comment: Also reproduced on 1.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After diving into Apiman code, I just found out that those variables are replaced by System.env properties.
In order to override them, it's possible to add those lines after 'extensions' tag into the standalone-apiman.xml configuration that you are using to run apiman :

```
<system-properties>
       <property name="apiman.gateway-endpoint" value="http://apiman.gateway.com"/>
       <property name="apiman.gateway-endpoint.username" value="username"/>
       <property name="apiman.gateway-endpoint.password" value="password"/>
</system-properties>
```